# Resolving name clashes with builtins in a see also documentation section

Tags: matlab, class, documentation, shadowing, token-name-resolution

I have the following class, with a method that hides (or *shadows*) a builtin function. I want the documentation to contain a "See Also" section, that links to the builtin function that is hidden.

```
classdef CatHelper
  %CATHELPER Makes implementing vertcat/horzcat easy on a custom class
  %
  %   See Also: cat

  methods (Abstract)
    obj = cat(obj, ndim, varargin);
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, the "see also" link just tries to give help on the undocumented abstract method `CatHelper/cat`.

How do I specify that I want the link to go to the *builtin* `cat` function?

Comment: I think it has to be all caps `See also: CAT`.

Comment: @mpaskov: Nope, that does the same thing. Both produce a link, but in both cases the link goes to `matlab:help CatHelper/cat`

Comment: what about if you try to link to a completely different function e.g.`min`/`max`, just to make sure there is no name clash.

Comment: @mpaskov: Then that works fine. My issue here is specifically about resolving the name clash. I've updated my question title to make that clear

Comment: Thanks for clarification, it seems that you might have found the answer yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After playing around a bit with `doc.m\resolveTopic()`, I came up with the three options as shown below. The top one (`\cat`) gives the best result, but you should use whichever you feel is the least ambiguous in your case.

```
%   See Also: \cat
%   See Also: elmat\cat
%   See Also: matlab\elmat\cat
```

These were found by passing `topic = 'cat'` into:

```
matlab.internal.language.introspective.resolveName(topic, '', false);
```

Answer (score 0):

One slightly ugly workaround is to just include a direct link:

```
%   See Also: <a href="matlab:help cat">cat</a>
```